# 400 Bad Request - Network Specific

Tags: http, get, request

I get a 400 Bad Request error when trying to load medium.com. This only happens on my home network (if I take my laptop outside my network on turn off wifi on my phone, the site loads). I have cleared my cache, cookies, and browsing history on every device, restarted every device, and restarted my modem, to no avail.  I searched this site for answers, but all the questions asked seem to be related to development, and at the moment, I'm just trying to load a page. How can I fix this? Thanks!